# How to draw a tikz diagram with a rectangular u-shaped edge connecting two blocks?

Tags: tikz-arrows, draw, tikz-graphdrawing

I am trying to draw the red arrow between the two blocks

[image]

However, I have no idea how to do it. Could please someone draw it and show me code?

Comment: One of several methods: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/is-there-a-tikz-equivalent-to-the-pstricks-ncbar-command Or `\draw [->,red] (dataund) -- ++(0,-1cm) -| (busund);`, obviously changing the node names to whatever you've used.

Comment: I realize it's hard to search for things like this, but it's actually a very common question. Another couple of references: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102385/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522212/

Comment: Thanks that solves my problem

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot