# Add label onto chain join arrow lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

I would like to add some labels onto chain join arrow lines.

Any command can be added to join styles with labels?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=1.5cm,
    arrow/.style={->, >=Stealth, thick},
    every on chain/.append style={draw,join,rounded corners,minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center},
    every join/.style={arrow},
    start chain=C1 going right,
    ]

  \def\nodes{
    A/A2B,
    B/B2C,
    C/C2A%
    }
    \foreach \name/\label [count=\i] in \nodes {
      \typeout{debugme \label}
        \node[on chain,join] (N\i) {\name};
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: see the zarko's answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/522212/tikz-arrows-and-blocks/522230#522230

Comment: Your nodes are already named `C1-1`, `C1-2`, … by the `chains` library, by the way. The first is also available under the name `C1-begin` and the currently last under `C1-end`. Since you've added `join` to both the `every on chain` style as well as the options of the node, the arrows are actually drawn twice. Since the answers also use the `join` with the node, I'd remove the `join` from the `every on chain` style.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From js bibra's answer, with `chain-end` and `chain-begin`

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                %positioning,
                % scopes,
                quotes,}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=1.5cm,
        arrow/.style={->, >=Stealth, thick},
        every on chain/.append style={draw,join,rounded corners,minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center},
        every join/.style={arrow},
        start chain=going right,
        ]
        
        \def\nodes{
            A/,
            B/A2B,
            C/B2C%
        }
        \foreach \name/\label [count=\i] in \nodes {
            % \node[on chain,join=by {->,"\label"}] (N\i) {\name};
            \node[on chain,join=by {"\label"}] (N\i) {\name};
            }    
        \draw [arrow] (chain-end.south) -- ++(0,-1.) -|  (chain-begin.south) node[above,pos=0.25]{C2A};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer +1 but can we get the feedback loop into the chain syntax that is where I got stuck

Comment: @jsbibra [`\chainin (<name>-begin) [join=by {<special>, "C2A"}];`](https://tikz.dev/library-chains#pgf.back/chainin) where `<name>` is the name of the chain (`chain` in this answer, `C1` in OP's MWE, though `N1` can be used) and `<special>` is any option that are allowed for the join (which is just an edge), so any `to path` specification, etc. Though, this makes `chain-end` the first node again. You can also `join=with <name>-begin by {<special>, "C2A"}` on the last node but have to reverse the direction, I guess. Best be done with a late option so we don't have to check this inside the loop.

Comment: Nice answer, which part need the quotes library?

Comment: @lucky1928 For `join=by {"\label"}`

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer since the last node shows up as an empty box- could not find out how to delete it - probably some of the veterans will step in to help

Output

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,positioning,scopes,quotes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=1.5cm,
        arrow/.style={->, >=Stealth, thick},
        every on chain/.append style={draw,join,rounded corners,minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center},
        every join/.style={arrow},
        start chain=C1 going right,
        ]
        
        \def\nodes{
            A/,
            B/A2B,
            C/B2C,
              /C2A%
        }
        \foreach \name/\label [count=\i] in \nodes {
            \node[on chain,join=by {->,"\label"}] (N\i) {\name};
        }
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Defining `ch-4/.style=coordinate` and then doing `ch-\i/.try` would be the easiest while not very flexible. We could also allow some special case of `\name` that would trigger this, e.g. empty if no other node could be empty. A special treatment for the [last item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16198) in PGFFor would be nice.